# Change color of points in three.js point cloud buffergeometry

Tags: three.js

I am building a simple app that displays a point cloud video.
I want it to cycle through different point clouds at some specific frame rate.

Currently the position of each points changes as I want, but for some reason the colors are not updating. They just stay white.

Here's the jsfiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/jjough/2uwp6mqr/

```
var scene, renderer, camera;
var cube;
var controls;
var tgeometry;
var pointCloud;
var nbPoints = 500;
var INTERVAL_DURATION = 500;
var MAX_POINTS = 100000;
var currentPointsIndex = 0;
var currentPoints = 0;
var currentTimestep = 0;
var interval;

var startTime = Date.now();

init();

animate();

interval = setInterval(function() {
  setPoints();
}, INTERVAL_DURATION)


// some randomly generated data. two point clouds, each with 4 points
var data_xyz = [[[1.8268303127880967, -0.16895618685053237, -1.8384542433636089], [0.10297754734589952, 0.3851586497177374, 0.05018245416897573], [-2.1180798955888385, -0.6258789390249381, -0.4864819299757507], [-1.9369768985250173, 0.31450389846935795, 0.6346786832304544]], [[-0.016824123971404495, 1.9396074401037642, 0.43754527308924274], [-2.39602366377225, 0.09685160862462244, 0.19810004276648954], [-1.19132463333637, -1.2798379064589926, -0.24002961031280587], [1.8350352795559735, -0.28378543753167934, 2.4226851359270243]]]

var data_color = [[[0.9283037768732556, 0.1057777112621947, 0.6112961465608326], [0.35444448049318833, 0.5568149518418057, 0.9135465231278102], [0.7801392850962043, 0.5461347052967598, 0.08969984826560384], [0.4637490610227777, 0.8788191706067839, 0.7854789512804808]], [[0.9673365640014331, 0.33305088656497794, 0.7323643699420422], [0.018088016871175228, 0.02136375617509534, 0.9314182214669771], [0.844695305010425, 0.7188791022449263, 0.600067066091458], [0.25036800594943853, 0.9710434742819252, 0.6482289815895979]]]




function setPoints() {

    var positions = pointCloud.geometry.attributes.position.array;
    var colors = pointCloud.geometry.attributes.color.array;

        var x, y, z, index;

    var l  = currentPoints + nbPoints;
    if(l >= MAX_POINTS) {
        clearInterval(interval);
      console.log('Milliseconds to render ' + MAX_POINTS +' points: ');
      console.log( Date.now() - startTime);    
      console.log('Expected milliseconds: ' + (INTERVAL_DURATION * MAX_POINTS / nbPoints));
    }
    currentPointsIndex = 0
    arr_xyz = data_xyz[currentTimestep]
    arr_color = data_color[currentTimestep++]
    if (currentTimestep == data_xyz.length){currentTimestep=0}

    for(var i=0; i < arr_xyz.length; i++) {
        point_xyz = arr_xyz[i];
      point_color = arr_color[i];
      positions[ currentPointsIndex   ] = point_xyz[0];
      colors[ currentPointsIndex ++  ] = point_color[0];
      positions[ currentPointsIndex   ] = point_xyz[1];
      colors[ currentPointsIndex ++  ] = point_color[1];
       positions[ currentPointsIndex   ] = point_xyz[2];
      colors[ currentPointsIndex ++  ] = point_color[2];
    }

    currentPoints = currentPointsIndex;
    pointCloud.geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true; 
    pointCloud.geometry.attributes.color.needsUpdate = true;    
    pointCloud.geometry.setDrawRange( 0, currentPoints );  
    update();

}

function update() {

  controls.update();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function init() {
      renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( {antialias:true} );
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight;
    renderer.setSize (width, height);
    document.body.appendChild (renderer.domElement);
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera (45, width/height, 1, 1000);
    camera.position.y = 8;
    camera.position.z = 40;
    camera.lookAt (new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0));

        console.log(THREE);
    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls (camera, renderer.domElement);

    var tmaterial = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
      size: 2,
      opacity: 1
    });


    tgeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
    var positions = new Float32Array( MAX_POINTS * 3 ); // 3 vertices per point
    var colors = new Float32Array( MAX_POINTS * 3 ); // 3 colors per point
        tgeometry.addAttribute( 'position', new THREE.BufferAttribute( positions, 3 ) );
    tgeometry.addAttribute( 'color', new THREE.BufferAttribute( colors, 3 ) );
      pointCloud = new THREE.Points(tgeometry, tmaterial);
    scene.add(pointCloud);
        window.addEventListener ('resize', onWindowResize, false);
}

function onWindowResize () {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize (window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

function animate() {
        controls.update();
    requestAnimationFrame ( animate );  
        renderer.render (scene, camera);
}
```

Comment: Seems to be an index offset error. I would recommend you remove all your `++` from the code, it make it harder to follow, instead follow the style in the examples with syntax such as ```for(var i = 0, i3 = 0; i < arr_xyz.length; i += 1, i3 += 3) {
      positions[i3 + 0] = arr_xyz[i][0];
      positions[i3 + 1] = arr_xyz[i][1];```

Comment: Could it also possibly be that your material is not set to read these colors? Something like `vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors` should make it read the actual colors, not the basic color of the marerial? *Edit* Jup.

Comment: Oh, good catch @somethinghere

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your `PointsMaterial` to make it read the colors you defined:

```
vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors
```

Otherwise it will fall back to white, the default color of the material.

- I tested it in your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2uwp6mqr/4/
- You can find it at `vertexColors` in the docs: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/materials/Material
- And the constants for materials in the docs here: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/constants/Materials